# Why @WebFluxTest enable Spring Security in Spring Boot 2.1.0.RELEASE

Tags: spring, spring-boot, reactive-programming, spring-webflux

I tried to upgrade [my sample](https://github.com/hantsy/angular-spring-reactive-sample) to Spring Boot 2.1.0.RELEASE, the [PostControllerTest](https://github.com/hantsy/angular-spring-reactive-sample/blob/master/server/src/test/java/com/example/demo/PostControllerTest.java) which used `@WebFluxTest` failed due to Spring Security protection. But in the initial version(Spring Boot 2.0.0.M7) it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the expected behavior as of Spring Boot 2.1.0. It's been implemented in [spring-boot#13632](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/13632) and a [similar issue has been raised already about this](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/15073). We're aligning with the behavior of Spring MVC auto-configuration here.

You can learn [how to improve your test configuration in the Spring Security documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.1.x/reference/html5/#test-method-setup).

Comment: It is great, but I hope there is a `secure`(default is false) attribute in the `@WebFluxTest`.

Comment: There's no `secure` attribute on `@WebFluxTest` as that attribute has been deprecated on `@WebMvcTest` in favour of using Spring MVC's testing support.

Comment: I have security configuration that permits all for GET requests, WebFluxTest however ignores this configuration and wants all requests to be authorized. Not sure if there is something I am missing for WebFluxTest to use specific Security Configurations?

Comment: @Brian Any update on this?. I am using 2.2.1 version. And its still the same.

Comment: I have a similar issue as @Hantsy. After spending hours trying, my WebFluxTest still returns a 403 FORBIDDEN error because of a missing CSRF token. I will roll back to the previous state: i.e. not using spring security.